# Multiple tags for BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```py
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get a list of all .htm files in the HTML_bak folder
html_files = [file for file in os.listdir('HTML_bak') if file.endswith('.htm')]

# Loop through each HTML file
for file_name in html_files:
    input_file_path = os.path.join('HTML_bak', file_name)
    output_file_path = os.path.join('HTML', file_name)
    
    # Read the input file with errors='ignore'
    with open(input_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as input_file:
        input_content = input_file.read()

    # Parse the input content using BeautifulSoup with html5lib parser
    soup = BeautifulSoup(input_content, 'html5lib')

    main_content = soup.find('div', style='position:initial;float:left;text-align:left;overflow-wrap:break-word !important;width:98%;margin-left:5px;background-color:#FFFFFF;color:black;')
  
    # Overwrite the output file with modified content
    with open(output_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        output_file.write(str(main_content))
```

This code correctly scans HTML files in a folder and only pulls in the desired `div` based on `style`. However, there are sometimes tags within this `div` tag that I want to remove. Those tags appear as:

`<div class="gmail_quote">2010/2/11 some text here .... </div>`

How can I edit my code to also remove these tags with `gmail_quote` class?

**Update 8/29/23:**

I am copying an example HTML content to make sure my question is clear. I want to keep the contents of the `<div style="position:initial....` after `<body bgColor=#ffffff>` and remove the contents of the `<div class="gmail_quote">2010/2/11 ...`

```html
<html><body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"><div></div></body></html><article style="width:100%;float:left; position:left;background-color:#FFFFFF; margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm; "><style>
@media print {
pre { overflow-x:break-word; white-space:pre; white-space:hp-pre-wrap; white-space:-moz-pre-wrap; white-space:-o-pre-wrap;  white-space:-pre-wrap; white-space:pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word;}
}pre { overflow-x:break-word; white-space:pre; white-space:hp-pre-wrap; white-space:-moz-pre-wrap; white-space:-o-pre-wrap;  white-space:-pre-wrap; white-space:pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word;}
@page {size: auto; margin: 12mm 4mm 12mm 6mm; }
</style>
<div style="position:initial;float:left;background-color:transparent;text-align:left;width:100%;margin-left:5px;">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8;"><style>
.hdrfldname{color:black;font-size:20px; line-height:120%;}
.hdrfldtext{overflow-wrap:break-word;color:black;font-size:20px;line-height:120%;}
</style></head>
<body bgColor=#ffffff>
<div style="position:initial;float:left;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;width:100%;background-color:#eee9e9;">
<span class='hdrfldname'>SUBJECT: </span><span class='hdrfldtext'>lorem ipsum</span><br>
<span class='hdrfldname'>FROM: </span><span class='hdrfldtext'>lorem ipsum</span><br>
<span class='hdrfldname'>TO: </span><span class='hdrfldtext'>lorem ipsum</span><br>
<span class='hdrfldname'>DATE: </span><span class='hdrfldtext'>2010/02/12 09:10</span><br>
</div></body></html>
</div>
<div style="position:initial;float:left;text-align:left;overflow-wrap:break-word !important;width:98%;margin-left:5px;background-color:#FFFFFF;color:black;"><br>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8;"><style>
pre { overflow-x:break-word; white-space:pre; white-space:hp-pre-wrap; white-space:-moz-pre-wrap; white-space:-o-pre-wrap;  white-space:-pre-wrap; white-space:pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word;}
</style></head><body bgColor=#ffffff>
<div> lorem ipsum </div>

<div class="gmail_quote">2010/2/11 lorem ipsum<span dir="ltr">&lt;<a  style="max-width:100%;" href="lorem ipsum">lorem ipsum</a>&gt;</span><br>

</body></html>
</div>
</article>
<div>&nbsp;<br></div>
```

Comment: `main_content.contents` will strip out all of the tags, although I think it's going to leave the contents of those tags.

Comment: I am looking to keep everything inside the `div` except remove all contents within the child `div` with the `gmail_quote` class.

Comment: @misaligar Well, filter out those tags (`find_all("div", class_="gmail_quote")`) and remove them by calling `decompose()` on them.

Comment: @TARN4T1ON But I don't know how to combine the two separate commands. How can I run the `find_all` command on the `main_content` variable which contains the parent `div` tags?

Comment: @misaligar `main_content` is an object of the class [`bs4.Tag`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#bs4.Tag), not a string or even a list or dict, so it has member attributes and functions, including `find_all()`. So it really is as simple as `main_content.find_all(...)` lol

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Comment: @misaligar That means that the `main_content` element wasn't found either (`soup.find()` returns `None` if it can't find it). Since you're iterating over multiple HTML files, are you sure that your selector works on all of them? It wasn't throwing an exception before, as you weren't doing anything other than using `main_content` to construct a string, which is still valid even if `main_content == None`, it just wrote "None" as the output. Once you try to access it's members, however... I just tested your example HTML, and it works just fine, so it has to be one of the others you're loading.

Comment: @TARN4T1ON That is exactly what happened! Thank you so much for your help. I implemented `try` `except` code to work around the files which don't have the `gmail_quote` class. And it works OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **modify your code** to remove the `div` tags with the `gmail_quote` class by using the `decompose()` method of the **BeautifulSoup library**. This method removes a tag from the tree and then completely destroys it and its contents.

```py
    # Find and remove all div tags with class gmail_quote
    for tag in main_content.find_all('div', {'class': 'gmail_quote'}):
        tag.decompose()
```

Add this code **below your** `main_content` line.

This should remove all `div` tags with the `gmail_quote` class from the `main_content` before writing it to **the output file**.

Comment: Damn, I can see why some people accuse some posters of using ChatGPT to write their answers. Not gonna lie, this really is written weirdly (especially the formatting). But who am I to judge, since this is otherwise 100% correct.

Comment: I didn't use it. Why is it written weirdly? English is not my mother language.

Comment: It doesn't work: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Comment: @misaligar Don't use the methods from the comments on your Post. Try my method from the code that you showed us all.

Comment: @Razzer I tried yours. Same error.

Comment: Then show us please your current code in order so we can help you. :)